# R: turn row values into column names and count its assigned values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
data.frame(name=c("a","a","b","b","c"),
value=c("2011-01-23","2011-01-23","2011-01-23","2011-01-22","2011-01-22"))

name     value
 a        2011-01-23
 a        2011-01-23
 b        2011-01-23
 b        2011-01-22
 c        2011-01-22
```

I only have 3 different names, and I would like to turn it into:

```
a    b   c   date
2    1   0    2011-01-23
0    1   1    2011-01-22
```

I looked at the reshape package, but I couldn't understand the documentation well enough to solved this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your `data.frame` is `dat`, and using `dcast()` from `reshape2`:

```
dcast(dat, value ~ name)

#        value a b c
# 1 2011-01-22 0 1 1
# 2 2011-01-23 2 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at `table`. `t(table(dat))` should do it (if your source object is named "dat"). Wrap the whole statement in `as.data.frame.matrix(.)` to get a `data.frame`.

```
t(table(dat))
#             name
# value        a b c
#   2011-01-22 0 1 1
#   2011-01-23 2 1 0
as.data.frame.matrix(t(table(dat)))
#            a b c
# 2011-01-22 0 1 1
# 2011-01-23 2 1 0
```